# Displaying data once using JSTL

Tags: jstl

I have a model object which has the ff. properties:

1. Group
2. Sub group
3. name

The object is on a `List<Model>` which I iterate like this:

```
<c:forEach var="itemBean" items="${ itemBeanList }">
   <option value="${ itemBean.group }">${ itemBean.group }</option>
   <option value="${ itemBean.subGroup }">${ itemBean.subGroup }</option>
   <option value="${ itemBean.name }">${ itemBean.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

But I want to display the group and subGroup only once. Is their a function or a way to do this in JSTL?Or can you suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using varStatus attribute in forEach and c:if jstl tag as:

```
    <c:forEach var="itemBean" items="${itemBeanList" varStatus="itemStatus">
        <c:if test="${itemStatus.count == 1}">
            <option value="${ itemBean.group }">${ itemBean.group }</option>
            <option value="${ itemBean.subGroup }">${ itemBean.subGroup }</option>
        </c:if>
        <option value="${ itemBean.name }">${ itemBean.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
```

Loop status:

```
    ${itemStatus.index} starts at 0
    ${itemStatus.count} starts at 1
```

You can find more information about loop status [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html).